# What is the wildcard specifying one or two characters?

Tags: command-line, bash, wildcards

Is there a simpler way to write:
`wc -l foo?.txt foo??.txt` ?

Since in my case I have (at most) two digit numbers, I tried using the range specification `wc -l foo[1-99].txt` but this ended up displaying only results between 1 and 9 (instead of 99). But this is a (nonworking) hack, and I really need something like `wc -l foo[?,??].txt`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you have two or more choices, use *brace expansion*:

```
foo{?,??}.txt
```

Or, to be more specific:

```
foo{[0-9],[0-9][0-9]}.txt
```

#### Example

Let's consider a directory with these three files:

```
$ ls foo*txt
foo111.txt  foo11.txt  foo1.txt
```

Observe:

```
$ echo foo{?,??}.txt
foo1.txt foo11.txt
```

And:

```
$ echo foo{[0-9],[0-9][0-9]}.txt
foo1.txt foo11.txt
```

Or, more concisely:

```
$ echo foo{,[0-9]}[0-9].txt
foo1.txt foo111.txt
```

Comment: He does not want 0 though ;)

Comment: Thank you. Is this information [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CommandlineHowto)  (see wildcards/range) then bogus?

Comment: @Matsmath I just tested the example from that documentation and it fails for me.  The range `[2-23]` means any one of the characters 2 through 2 or the character 3.  So, yes, the documentation looks bogus.

Comment: @John1024 no you need the `shopt -s extglob`

Comment: For the last, `{,[0-9]}[0-9]` works too with less typing.

Comment: @Random832 Very good.  I added that to the answer.

Answer (score 4):

With bash's *extended glob* (`extglob`) syntax, you can use `foo@(?|??)` e.g.

```
wc -l foo@(?|??).txt
```

The `extglob` option should be enabled by default in the interactive shell on current Ubuntu releases, but if not you can enable it using

```
shopt -s extglob
```